# Unable to run Testng Maven Project with TestComplete

Tags: testng, maven-plugin, testcomplete

I have one Maven Project that have TestNg Classes and it is running fine with eclipse. I want to run same project with TestComplete , perform all the prerequisites as defined under TestComplete integration. I have attached the screen shot of error that i am facing.

Please Help it is urgent.[error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkuFd.png)

Comment: The error says `cannot find the file specified`. What file is your setup referring to? Have you looked at that part ?

Comment: Test COmplete was unable to compile the maven project as system environment PATH variable was not correctly set. Check my response below if any one looking for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your maven project test classes uses relative file paths for loading drivers or maybe some other configuration file.

FYI, when you are running a maven project test class from Testcomplete, your relative path reference changes to the TestComplete project folder (where .pjs file is located) . *It is **not** the root folder where your pom.xml resides*.

So you have to update those file paths references to TC project location. Move those guest project/files to TC project folder , if required.

Answer (score 0):

i want to share my experience as maven System environment was not set correctly under PATH system variable..
It was - %M2_HOME%bin
I changed it to correct - %M2_HOME%**/**bin

and it start working.